# Implicit functions, looking to perform different math functions based on a key

Tags: python, function, dictionary

The title is a bit weird but I couldn't think of a better way to phrase it. I'm working on a plugin for a 3D software. It stores data in things called "channels", and the plugin I'm working on is synchronising different "channels" based on some mathematical relationships. Basically something like this:

If the user updates channel "quality" I want to update "rays" and "ratio" according to a formula. If they update "rays" or "ratio" I want to update just "quality". There are a whole bunch of different things I need to update, not just these ones, but I'll keep it simple for the sake of... well, simplicity.

At the moment I've got a dictionary which is a list of channels to be updated for each channel-that-got-update key, like this:

```
channel_relationships = {
"quality": ["rays", "ratio"],
"rays":    ["quality"],
"ratio":   ["quality"]
}
```

That's working well for figuring out what's changing. My code gets a value sent to it to notify it of which channel was changed by the user, so I simply access the right list by using the right key from the dictionary:

```
channels_to_update = channel_relationships[incoming_channel]
for channel in channels_to_update:
     UpdateChannel(channel)
```

That's all fine and dandy. But the tricky thing is that all the different channels affect each-other in different ways using some rather long math expressions. Currently I'm solving that by a bunch of if/elif statements in my UpdateChannel function, something like this:

```
def UpdateChannel(channel):
    if channel == "rays":
        pass #do math here
    elif channel == "ratio":
        pass #do other math...
    elif channel == "quality"
        pass #do other math...
```

Which is not very elegant. Ideally I'd want to store the functions themselves in an implicit way in a dictionary, like this:

```
functions = {"quality": {"rays": 0.5*x**2+3.2*x+2, 
                         "ratio": 7.3*x**2+1.2*x-5}}
```

Basically storing the functions themselves directly in the dictionary. Note that I'd rather not actually *calculate* all the values in the dictionary. I want them to only be evaluated as needed. So when I access functions["quality"]["rays"] I want to get either the implicit function, or the value as calculated based on "x". Something like that. The problem is, I have no idea if this is even *possible* in Python, nor do I have any idea where to start looking for such a thing. I could just define my functions explicitly for each relationship, but I'd end up with a LOT of functions. Because all the functions are literally just a single floating point value based on an input floating point value, this seems like the most elegant way of doing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions are first-class objects, you can store them in dictionaries, retrieve them, *then* call them, no problem.

A `lambda` will produce a function from a single expression:

```
functions = {
    "quality": {
        "rays": lambda x: 0.5*x**2+3.2*x+2, 
        "ratio": lambda x: 7.3*x**2+1.2*x-5
    }
}
```

Now look up your functions and call them:

```
functions['quality']['rays'](input_float_value)
```

Yes, it is that simple. :-)

Comment: `def`ined functions are also objects and can be passed by name if the lambda gets to long